# How to Combine 4 MYSQL query in one ASP GridView

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I want to get the result for the following query in one gridview

**Result Should be**

```
Early|Late|Excess
```

---

```
SELECT reports.inone, SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,reports.inone,date_FORMAT(reports.inone,'%Y-%m-%d 08:00:00') ))) AS early
FROM `wave`.`reports` 
WHERE personnelnr=12793 
    and reportdate between "2015/01/01" and "2015/10/01" 
    and date_FORMAT(reports.inone,'%T') < '08:00:00' 
    and time_to_sec(reports.inone) <  28200
```

---

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( sum(TIME_TO_SEC(reports.lateone ))) AS Late
FROM `wave`.`reports` 
where personnelnr=12319 
    and reportdate between "2015/09/01" and "2015/09/30"
    and reports.lateone >= '00:10:00';
```

---

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( sum(TIME_TO_SEC(reports.otone))) AS Excess
FROM `wave`.`reports` 
where  personnelnr=12319 
    and reportdate between "2015/09/01" and "2015/09/30" 
    and reports.otone >= '00:10:00';
```

what should I use Dataset? and i don't want to make all query in one Sql Statement  please help?